# Typescript: cannot cast value from json to [number, number] tuple

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm pretty new to TypeScript. Maybe my question is obvious, but I can't find any solution.

I have a config.json file like this:

```
{
  "api": {
    "baseUrl": "http://localhost:9000/api",
    "list": {
      "itemsPerPage": 200
    }
  },
  "map": {
    "start": {
      "position": [51.505, -0.09],
      "zoom": 2
    },
    "leaflet": {
      "minOpacity": 0.3,
      "accessToken": "something"
    }
  }
}
```

I import it into some module.tsx

```
import config from '../config.json';
const mapCenter: [number, number] = config.map.start.position;
```

`position` from json need to be treated as `[number, number]` tuple, because some library that I use requires it to be typed like this.
But unfortunately I get an error:

> TS2322: Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type '[number, number]'.
>   Property '0' is missing in type 'number[]'.

How to cast types correctly?

Can I declare type of my json using config.d.ts file? How?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Tuples in typescript are glorified arrays, you can use the "as" keyword to cast it to your type:

```
const mapCenter: [number, number] = config.map.start.position as [number, number];
```

Comment: So easy? Thank you very much.

Comment: If you want to learn more about typescript type assertions -> https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html